# Hadoop post-hook and job completation notification

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, notifications

I would like to import my Hadoop job output to Hive table. How do I implement a post-hooking in a map-reduce job/flow? Or any other automated options?

Also I would a notification after the job is done, such as sending a email to user. I found this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-1111, but I don't quite understand how to do it since I'm new to map-reducing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conf.set("mapreduce.job.end-notification.url","url")`

would do. The `url` should be an `http url` where you would receive the callback.

From javadocs :

> Set the uri to be invoked in-order to send a notification after the job has completed (success/failure).
>
> The uri can contain 2 special parameters: $jobId and $jobStatus. Those, if present, are replaced by the job's identifier and completion-status respectively.
>
> This is typically used by application-writers to implement chaining of Map-Reduce jobs in an asynchronous manner.

Note that older hadoop versions use `job.end.notification.url`.
It has been deprecated in newer versions in favour of `mapreduce.job.end-notification.url`.

Reference [`mapred-default.xml#mapreduce.job.end-notification.url`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml#mapreduce.job.end-notification.url).